# Class loading in websphere 8.5

Tags: java, websphere-8

What is class loading? How it works for websphere 8.5? What it means by parent last and parent first?

My Application works when i setup Single Class Loader and not when i go for separate class loader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class loading is not specific to WebSphere, it's basic Java.

With IBM WebSphere the developer can define some settings for the class loader.

**Class-loader isolation policies**: *Single* or *Multiple*
Controls the isolation of applications that are running in the system. When set to Single, applications are not isolated. When set to Multiple, applications are isolated from each other.

**Order**: *parent first* or *parent last*
Specifies whether the class loader searches in the parent class loader or in the application class loader first

Source: [IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/crun_classload.html)

What's the exact Error you get, when using *Multiple* Class Loaders?
Maybe your application needs to provide a dependency (JAR) that with *Single* class loader is found in another application also deployed on this WAS instance.